# elasticsearch: how to define mapping with nested fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going to define mapping with nested fields. according to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html), payload to `/order-statistics/_mapping/order` looks like:

```
{
  "mappings" : {
  "order": {
    "properties" : {
      "order_no" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "order_products" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "order_product_no" : {
            "type" : "int"
          },
          "order_product_options" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "order_product_option_no" : {
                "type" : "int"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

I've already created the `order-statistics` index with a call to `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/order-statistics'` and I'm using predefined types such as `int`, `string`, `double`, But I get the following error and can't find what wrong with.

```
{  
    "error":{  
        "root_cause":[  
            {  
                "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {order={properties={order_no={type=string}, order_products={type=nested, properties={order_product_no={type=int}, order_product_options={type=nested, properties={order_product_option_no={type=int}}}}}}}}]"
            }
        ],
        "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {order={properties={order_no={type=string}, order_products={type=nested, properties={order_product_no={type=int}, order_product_options={type=nested, properties={order_product_option_no={type=int}}}}}}}}]"
    },
    "status":400
}
```

could someone explain why this not work?

Comment: Which version do you use, string is deprecated in newest version, also "int" should be "integer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `int` as type for some fields which is not a valid type in either 2.x or 5.x. For integer values, please use `integer` or `long` depending on the values you want to store. For details, please see [the docs on core mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#core-fields).

Which version of elasticsearch are you using - 2.x or 5.x? If you are on 5.x already, you should go with `keyword` or `text` for your string fields instead of using just `string` which was the naming up to 2.x. But this is still only a warning.

Additionally, you should be aware of the implications when using `nested` instead of just `object`. Using a nested type is necessary if you store an array of objects and want to query for more than one property of such an object with the guarantee that only these documents match where one of the nested objects in the array matches all your conditions. But this comes at a cost, so consider using the simple `object` type, if this works for you. For more details, please see [the docs on nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/nested.html) and especially [the warning at the end](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/nested.html#_limiting_the_number_of_literal_nested_literal_fields).

Comment: I'm using ES 5.5.1 and Changing `int` to `integer` works for me.